# PHP imagecopyresampled Does not seem to scale Resize Image

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

Here is my code im not seeing my problem... Nay help would be thanked!

Now it Uploads Changes Quality and Copy to my directory but the pixels remain the same on Big or Small Images

Not sure where my problem as i have checked a few dozen examples and all look like my code im stuck any help would be great!

```
    //Upload Directory Build
    $uploaddir = './images/projects_data/' . $_POST['table'] . '/' . $id;
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . '/' . $db_picture;

if (isset($_FILES['images']['name'])) {
//Make Full Directory
if (!file_exists($uploaddir . '/full')) {
mkdir($uploaddir . '/full', 0775, true);
}

//Upload Full Size Thumbnails
foreach ($_FILES['images']['error'] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];

    //Max Height Width
$maxwidth = 100;

    //Read filetype  
        $i = strrpos($name,".");  
    if (!$i) { return ""; }  
    $l = strlen($name) - $i;  
    $extension = substr($name,$i+1,$l);  
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

    if ($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" || $extension=="pjpeg" ) {$modifiedimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);} 
elseif ($extension=="png") {$modifiedimage = imagecreatefrompng($tmp_name);} 
elseif ($extension=="gif") {$modifiedimage = imagecreatefromgif($tmp_name);}  

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($tmp_name);  

    //Change dimensions  
    $newwidth = $maxwidth;  
    $newheight = ($height/$width)*$newwidth;  

//Create Image And Copy
    $newdim = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);  
    imagecopyresampled($newdim,$modifiedimage,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);  
    imagejpeg($modifiedimage,$uploaddir . '/full/' . $name,60);  

    // Remove temp images  
    imagedestroy($modifiedimage);  
    imagedestroy($newdim);  

    //move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploaddir . '/full/' . $name);
echo '<span class="mainpagefontadmin">Project Photo Uploaded - Data Saved to: ' . $uploaddir . '/full/' . $name . '</span><br>';

    }
}
```

Comment: you don't appear to be saving the resized image. Where is the imagejpeg call that uses the $newdim handle... maybe you meant `imagejpeg($newdim,$uploaddir . '/full/' . $name,60);`

Comment: Omg duh so tired lol not sure why i didnt catch that thanks so much!

Code should be:
imagejpeg($newdim,$uploaddir . '/full/' . $name,60);

Comment: You got it! Duh..... Stupid sometimes when tired thanks bud!